# Looking for help using setInterval on the 2nd enemy in this simple run game

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for help to use setInterval on the second enemy in this simple runner game.

Ultimately I am trying to use on both of them so that they are displayed intermittently from one another, but when I add a separate setInterval and try add in runEnemy2 console is giving me an error saying that "enemy 2 is not defined in runEnemy". I thought each enemy should be in separate  functions so I'm guessing it's probably the ways it's written .

The way the code is here runEnemy is displayed as it should be, but if I try to use runEnemy2 nothing shows up.

```
<!-- begin snippet: -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    $(function () {
      var runGame;
      var dones = false;

      var runEnemy = function () {//ENEMY
        var enemy = $(".enemy");
        var properties = {
          right: $(".container").width(),
          display: "block"
        };

      var runEnemy2 = function () {//ENEMY2
        var enemy2 = $(".enemy2");
        
        };




        var options = { //ENEMY ATTACK DURATION
          duration: 2500,
          done: function () {
            var w = $(this).width() * -1;
            $(this).css({
              right: w
            });
          },
        };

          var options2 = { //ENEMY2 ATTACK DURATION
          duration: 5000,
          done: function () {
            var w2 = $(this).width() * -1;
            $(this).css({
              right: w2
            });
          },

          progress: function () {
            console.log(overlaps($(".hero"), $(".enemy"), $(".enemy2")));

            var laped = overlaps($(".hero"), $(".enemy"), $(".enemy2"));

            var heroLoc = document.getElementsByClassName("hero")[0].offsetTop;
            var enemyLoc = document.getElementsByClassName("enemy")[0].offsetTop;
            var enemy2Loc = document.getElementsByClassName("enemy2")[0].offsetTop;
            var loc = enemyLoc + enemy2Loc - heroLoc;

            console.log(
              "enemy: " + enemyLoc + enemy2Loc + " hero: " + heroLoc + " loc: " + loc
            );
            

            //Hitbox
            if (loc > 0 && laped === false) {
              dones = true;                     
              console.log("WIN");
            } else if (laped === true && loc < 0) {
              dones = false;
              $(".enemy").stop();
              $(".enemy2").stop();
              var score = parseInt($(".score").html());
              $(".hero").addClass("stopAnimate");
              $(".container").addClass("stopAnimate");
              $(".lose p").html("You Scored : " + score);
              clearInterval(runGame);
              $(".lose").addClass("lost");
              console.log("LOSE");
            }
          },

          complete: function () {
            if (dones === true) {
              var score = parseInt($(".score").html());
              $(".score").html(score + 1);
            }
          }
        };

        enemy.animate(properties, options);
        enemy2.animate(properties, options2);
      };

      var overlaps = (function () {
        function getPositions(elem) {
          var pos, width, height;
          pos = $(elem).position();
          width = $(elem).width();
          height = $(elem).height();
          return [
            [pos.left, pos.left + width],
            [pos.top, pos.top + height]
          ];
        }

        function comparePositions(p1, p2) {//COMPARE POSITIONS 
          var r1, r2;
          r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
          r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
          return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
        }
        return function (a, b) {
          var pos1 = getPositions(a),
            pos2 = getPositions(b);
          return (
            comparePositions(pos1[0], pos2[0]) && comparePositions(pos1[1], pos2[1])
          );
        };
      })();

      // Events

      $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        console.log("JUMP");
        if (e.keyCode === 32) {
          if ($(".lose").hasClass("lost") === false) {
            $(".hero")
              .toggleClass("jump")
              .bind(
                "webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
                function (e) {
                  if ($(this).hasClass("jump")) {
                    console.log("DROP");
                    $(this).toggleClass("jump");
                  }
                }
              );
          }
        }
      });

      setTimeout(function () {
        runGame = setInterval(function () {
          runEnemy()
        }, 2000);//ENEMY INTERVAL 
      }, 0);//+INITIAL WAIT

    });

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work as expected.
Hope this might help.

One of the issue was there were some misplaced brackets.
And when I fixed the misplaced brackets I noticed that these two lines are trying to access the properties (enemy and enemy2) which are scoped inside the method runEnemy.

```js
enemy.animate(properties, options);
enemy2.animate(properties, options2);
```

I made runEnemy methods to return properties that above two line requires.

```js
$(function () {
  var runGame;
  var dones = false;

  var runEnemy = function () {//ENEMY
    var enemy = $(".enemy");
    var properties = {
      right: $(".container").width(),
      display: "block"
    };
    return {enemy, properties}
  };

  var runEnemy2 = function () {//ENEMY2
    var enemy2 = $(".enemy2");
    return {enemy2}
    };




    var options = { //ENEMY ATTACK DURATION
      duration: 2500,
      done: function () {
        var w = $(this).width() * -1;
        $(this).css({
          right: w
        });
      },
    };

      var options2 = { //ENEMY2 ATTACK DURATION
      duration: 5000,
      done: function () {
        var w2 = $(this).width() * -1;
        $(this).css({
          right: w2
        });
      },

      progress: function () {
        console.log(overlaps($(".hero"), $(".enemy"), $(".enemy2")));

        var laped = overlaps($(".hero"), $(".enemy"), $(".enemy2"));

        var heroLoc = document.getElementsByClassName("hero")[0].offsetTop;
        var enemyLoc = document.getElementsByClassName("enemy")[0].offsetTop;
        var enemy2Loc = document.getElementsByClassName("enemy2")[0].offsetTop;
        var loc = enemyLoc + enemy2Loc - heroLoc;

        console.log(
          "enemy: " + enemyLoc + enemy2Loc + " hero: " + heroLoc + " loc: " + loc
        );
        

        //Hitbox
        if (loc > 0 && laped === false) {
          dones = true;                     
          console.log("WIN");
        } else if (laped === true && loc < 0) {
          dones = false;
          $(".enemy").stop();
          $(".enemy2").stop();
          var score = parseInt($(".score").html());
          $(".hero").addClass("stopAnimate");
          $(".container").addClass("stopAnimate");
          $(".lose p").html("You Scored : " + score);
          clearInterval(runGame);
          $(".lose").addClass("lost");
          console.log("LOSE");
        }
      },

      complete: function () {
        if (dones === true) {
          var score = parseInt($(".score").html());
          $(".score").html(score + 1);
        }
        
      }
    };
    
    runEnemy().enemy.animate(runEnemy().properties, options);
    runEnemy2().enemy2.animate(runEnemy().properties, options2);

  var overlaps = (function () {
    function getPositions(elem) {
      var pos, width, height;
      pos = $(elem).position();
      width = $(elem).width();
      height = $(elem).height();
      return [
        [pos.left, pos.left + width],
        [pos.top, pos.top + height]
      ];
    }

    function comparePositions(p1, p2) {//COMPARE POSITIONS 
      var r1, r2;
      r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
      r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
      return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
    }
    return function (a, b) {
      var pos1 = getPositions(a),
        pos2 = getPositions(b);
      return (
        comparePositions(pos1[0], pos2[0]) && comparePositions(pos1[1], pos2[1])
      );
    };
  })();

  // Events

  $(this).keypress(function (e) {
    console.log("JUMP");
    if (e.keyCode === 32) {
      if ($(".lose").hasClass("lost") === false) {
        $(".hero")
          .toggleClass("jump")
          .bind(
            "webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
            function (e) {
              if ($(this).hasClass("jump")) {
                console.log("DROP");
                $(this).toggleClass("jump");
              }
            }
          );
      }
    }
  });

  setTimeout(function () {
    runGame = setInterval(function () {
      runEnemy()
    }, 2000);//ENEMY INTERVAL 
  }, 0);//+INITIAL WAIT

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try and let you know if it works.